# Trying to create a loop to export excel files from a list of data

Tags: r, export-to-excel

I have a list of data (150 student names + class + grade) and I am trying to create Excel sheets by *class*. I currently have a list of data broken up by class, but I am not able to export them into Excel.

```
IncomingClasses <- split(Students, Students$Class-Course)
classes <- names(IncomingClasses)

for (i in seq(classes)){
    assign(classes[i], IncomingClasses[[i]])
    write.xlsx(IncomingClasses[i], file = paste(i, ".xlsx"))
}
```

But I'm not able to export. The best error message I've gotten is:

> - Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :   arguments imply differing number of rows: 34,
>     44, 15, 17, 16, 18

Because I'm supposed to have different rows as there are different students in each class...but it won't create the .xlsx document.

Please help!

Comment: An important piece of information here would be which of the several Excel R packages you're using. xlsx? XLConnect? openxlsx? writexl? Something else?

Comment: Try this `library(tidyverse)`; `IncomingClasses %>%
  split(.$`Class-Course`) %>%
  walk2(names(.), ~ write_csv(.x, paste0(.y, '.csv')))`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I've got this data frame, initialised with these variables.

```
student <- c('joe', 'bob', 'foo', 'bar')
class <- c('1', '2', '3', '4')
grade <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
df <- data.frame(student, class,
```

Why not create a temporary data frame and save that to file, with the appropriate subset to entries with the correct class designation?

```
for (c in unique(df$class)) {
    tdf <- df[df$class == c, ]
    write.csv(tdf, file = paste(c, ".csv"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide a fully reproducible example of the problem, so it's hard to diagnose, but I see at least three problems. To access the split-up data frames, you should use `[[`, not `[`, your use of `seq` will produce numbered file names, and you should use `paste0` instead of `paste` to avoid inserting a space in the file names. Additionally, the use of `assign` is confusing. Might I suggest:

```
for (i in names(IncomingClasses)) {
  write.xlsx(IncomingClasses[[i]], file = paste0(i, '.xlsx'))
}
```

Comment: The will write separate files, however, and not separate sheets like OP requests.

Comment: Point taken, but nothing in the OP's code suggests separate sheets within the same document, and I've heard people use the term "sheets" to refer to the entire workbook (even though that is *technically* wrong).

Comment: The purpose of using assign is to create different data frames in R. I will be importing different data sets each time I use this code, so I'm trying to make it as general as possible. I tried the recommended code + now I'm getting **Error in mapply(setCellValue, cells[seq_len(nrow(cells)), colIndex[ic]],  : 
  zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length** because the first group of classes has no students.

Comment: `assign` is rarely needed for these types of operations. If you mean to apply the same operation to multiple objects, it's best to contain the objects in a list and employ functions that operate on the list members. `split` produces such a list to begin with.

Comment: Right, `assign` is basically only needed if you're going to programmatically construct objects/object names: `assign(paste0("test_", "mtcars"), mtcars)` for a basic example creates an object called `test_mtcars` with the `mtcars` data.